# Aspect of AspectJ with SpringAOP doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I know there are a lot of questions with the same problem, but I really don't understand what's the problem, as I tried to follow a lot of popular tutorials from scratch and it still doesn't work.

I ask you to have a look at my project here [link to github](https://github.com/BattleSlug/POC/tree/master/POC) and give a piece of advice as I really gave up to make it work.

I use Eclipse Luna + Tomcat 7, everything else you can see from the github as there is really not convenient to past everything here.

---

SOLVED: Actually, I think I need to be more specific with what I did to solve this puzzle: @tmarwen gave me a great tip off what could be wrong, I tested and saw that my dao-context.xml doesn't instantiate beans at all. So I moved all bean instantiation and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` to the separate `config.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` along with `web.xml` file. After that everything started working perfectly.

Comment: Do you try do AspectJ-Compiletime-Waving?

Comment: No, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that you had introduced a typo inside your root application config file path under *web.xml* file:

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:coms/config/dao-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

While it should be as follows (*com**s*** without an **s**):

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:com/config/dao-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

One more hint would be the context config file location, which I bet is not interpreted as a resource file at build time.

Since you are using *Maven* as your build tool, you may need to change the file location to be under the ***src/main/resoures*** directory (default directory being as the resources location for *Maven*), so that the whole path from your project root folder will be:

- *src/main/resoures/com/config/dao-context.xml*

Comment: The typo you are talking about is really just a typo in a commited project. Really I don't have one, so dao-context.xml usually is being read successfully.

Comment: You nailed it down precisely. My dao-context.xml was in wrong place, now it works. I appreciate your answer a lot and cordially wish you all the best.

Comment: Glad to be in help ;)